# Getting JMX working under Tomcat 7 with SSL and a self-signed cert

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jmx

I'm trying to get JMX working under Tomcat 7.0.23 with SSL.  The servers are located in AWS, which means all the hosts are NATed, and I need to use JmxRemoteLifecycleListener to explicitly set the two ports used by JMX.  I've been doing a lot of reading on the subject but I just can't get all the pieces working together properly.

I can get JMX working fine without SSL.  I have downloaded the version of catalina-jmx-remote.jar for my version of Tomcat and installed it in my tomcat/lib directory.  My server.xml contains:

```
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" 
        rmiRegistryPortPlatform="1099" rmiServerPortPlatform="1098" />
```

When I launch Tomcat with the following settings I can connect with an insecure session:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/path/to/jmxremote.password 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/path/to/jmxremote.access 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public IP of server> 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

However if I change these to the following then I'm unable to establish an SSL connection:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/path/to/jmxremote.password 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/path/to/jmxremote.access 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public IP of server> 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore.dat 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<password>
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.dat 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>
```

keystore.dat contains just a single certificate created via:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.pem -out cert.der
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.dat -file cert.der -storepass <password>
```

truststore.dat contains a full copy of the java cacerts plus the CA cert for my self-signed cert:

```
cp $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts truststore.dat
keytool -storepasswd -storepass changeit -new <password> -keystore truststore.dat
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file mycacert.pem -alias myalias -keystore truststore.dat -storepass <password>
```

After launching Tomcat I've tried connecting via jconsole but it can't establish a connection.  I tried to verify SSL using openssl but it looks like Tomcat isn't making use of the cert:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect <host>:1099
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735160957372:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 322 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I've verified that my local keystore and truststore are set up properly by exporting the keys and verifying the cert chain (combined.pem is all the CA certs from truststore.dat and cert.pem is my cert from keystore.dat):

```
$ openssl verify -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile combined.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK
```

So now I'm at a complete loss.  The cert and CA cert look correct.  Unencrypted JMX connections work.  But I can't seem to get the connection to use SSL. What am I missing here?

I don't know if this is just a red herring or not, but I don't see any way to specify what cert in the keyStore is used by JMX.  Some of what I read implies that it just uses a cert with the alias "tomcat".  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting the *RMI Registry* on port **1099**. In order for the *RMI Registry* to utilize **SSL** you need to pass an additional `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true` argument.

**Edit:**
Do you use `jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustword -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password` to start JConsole? It needs to know where the stores are and the corresponding passwords.

For VisualVM you can install **VisualVM-Security** plugin which will add a new tab to the Options dialogue allowing you customize the SSL related options in UI.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure how I missed that one.  Unfortunately adding it doesn't change the behavior in any way.  I still can't establish a secure connection from JConsole, and if I run the openssl s_client command it still generates the same "no peer certificate available" message.

Comment: I'm specifying the same keystore & truststore files when I launch jconsle, as you outline above.  But that doesn't change the behavior at all.  I'm not at all convinced that the problem is on the client end since I can't even get a valid SSL handshake when I run the "openssl s_client" command that I mentioned in the original question.  Since it says that no certificate is available and no CA names were sent then it looks to me like a problem on the server side.

Comment: If you use the same stores for the client and the server they must be "criss-crossed" - eg. 
Server: {truststore = store1, keystore = store2}, Client: {truststore = store2, keystore = store1}

Comment: Since he is using -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=false on the server-side, there is no need to provide a certificate on the client-side, neither import a client certificate in the server's keystore. The only thing the client need is the trustStore with the whole chain of authority for the server's certificate to validate.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted tomcat getting to work with jmx and ssl and followed Bruce setup. In case someone runs int the same problem: using the openssl and keytool commands form Bruce I was getting at client ssl errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Not sure why but the figerprint on one side was 5 chars longer at the beginning.

I recreated the keystore using:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -dname cn=test,ou=test,dc=example,dc=com
```

In tomcat sever.xml I added the listener as Bruce suggested.

Because client auth is set to false I do not add truststore in tomcat jmx configuration. Instead I added registry.ssl:

```
[...]
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_keystore_pass
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true
```

Then on client side as J.B. suggested I download ssl plugin for visualvm and criss-cross the keystore resulting in:

```
visualvm -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore.jks -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=your_keystore_pass
```

When adding authentication make sure that your jmx access file looks like:

```
<user_name>    readwrite
```

and your password file looks like:

```
<user_name>    <your_password>
```

This solved my ssl jmx setup for testing with visualm vm.

**Edit:**

Had some issues with having the registry also over SSL, set by:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true
```

leading at client to throw:

```
Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

Adding client auth authentication:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=your_trust_store_pass
```

solved both jmx and its registry to use ssl.

Comment: What helped me was the addition of -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true  to my existing configuration. This made the certificate show with openssl s_client