# How to connect to Tomcat7 JMX over SSL using catalina-ant?

Tags: ant, tomcat7, jmx

I have configured Tomcat JMX over SSL (similar to this [Getting JMX working under Tomcat 7 with SSL and a self-signed cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033379/getting-jmx-working-under-tomcat-7-with-ssl-and-a-self-signed-cert))

Now I am trying to execute `jmx:open` or `jmx:get` according to the following documentation:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html

Unfortunately, I cannot specify the trust store and therefore I get the following exception:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How to connect to Tomcat JMX over SSL using catalina-ant?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. You might want to look at this for a lead on how to get it going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033379/getting-jmx-working-under-tomcat-7-with-ssl-and-a-self-signed-cert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run it on Centos while I configure `ANT_OPTS` before `ant` commands execution:

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to trust store> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<trust store password>"
```

Please find example how to configure ANT_OPTS in Windows
http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#proxy